# configure GCDWebDAVServer to stream transport stream (.ts) files

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, drm, fairplay

I have done all required things, i have

1. .m3u8 file (also the data within it)
2. transport segment (.ts) files & asset id,certificate and response data
3. Server is also running

what i am trying to do is that on first run i download the files and the key data too then i saved data to NSUserDefaults which is used to decode or whatever is required

But AVPlayer fails to prepare for playback and give error

> The operation could not be completed
>   An unknown error occurred (-12158)

everything seems to be ok but it fails to stream play the files

Comment: are you able to live stream .ts file ?

Comment: well, that is what i was trying to do, mainly i was trying to play a DRM protected video!

Answer (score 0):

You should send the ckc to AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest.